# Why can we use both ln(n) and ln(n+1) for the Escher-Mascheroni constant?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am an undergrad in physics, I've never taken precalc or physics in hs so I feel like my math is a bit behind.

I'm trying to understand why the Escher-Masheroni constant can be defined in two different ways:
[version 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tatJ.png)

and

[version 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHrZL.png)

I decided to write out the series from n = 1 to infinity of ln(1+1/n) where everything cancels out and ln(1) goes to zero, I'm left with -ln(N+1) by subbing N to infinity. Why is it that the series is written from k=1 then n=1? in version 1, am I missing something?

Also I got ~0.59 when I did it with ln(n+1) vs 0.57...with ln(n). I thought the terms were supposed to decrease...

How do I prove the exact number? I get how I can use an upper and lower bound to say 1>gamma>0 but how do I get the value of the Escher-Masheroni constant?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(1+1/n)=0$, so it shouldn't matter in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Note that\begin{align}\require{cancel}\sum_{n=1}^N\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)&=\sum_{n=1}^N\ln\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)\\&=\sum_{n=1}^N\bigl(\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)\bigr)\\&=\ln(N+1)-\cancel{\ln(N)}+\cancel{\ln(N)}-\ln(N-1)+\cdots+\ln(2)-\smash{\overbrace{\ln(1)}^{\phantom0=0}}\\&=\ln(N+1).\end{align}